# Using Grid View to Paste Records: "Instance is read-only" error

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view

I am trying to paste data from Excel to a SharePoint list. But I keep getting the "Instance is ready-only" error. I've never encountered this before and have no clue what is going on:
[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what this error is and how to get rid of it?

Comment: What kind of list is it? Is it a standard list or a calendar for example? If so, some of these fields are grayed out. The All day event for example.

Comment: It's a custom (generic) list, not a calendar. I reduced the number of columns in a view to only two and this error still occurs.

Comment: OK, just checking. Are the data types matching? Single line of text fields and the Excel data doesn't exceed the length? No content approval turned on and no check out required?

Comment: Yes, I get this error in this list even when I have 2 text fields and I try to copy 1 row with very few characters. In fact, turns out that I get this problem when I add new records manually. It lets me input data to the first (Title) field, but as soon as I try entering data to the second text field, I get this "instance is read-only" error. I don't get this in other list. Maybe the issue is that the list is called "Projects" and it's some kind of a special list name?

Comment: I just created the same list in a different site and the is no issue there.  So it must be not related to the fact the list is called "Project". I think, I'll end up re-creating this list.

Comment: I created a list called Project in my 2016 on premise instance and named it Project, I have Title, Project ID (Single Line), Mutli (Multiple Lines of text), Current Date (Date).  I pasted 4 rows from Excel where my columns are formatted as general or Custom. It pasted as I'd expect in Edit mode using Chrome. Perhaps the Site Type is the issue. Is it a Document center, Records center, etc.  Mine is a Team site.

Comment: Thank you for trying it for me. I ended up deleting and recreating the list. The new list does not have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting and recreating the list. The new list does not have this issue. Why the issue occured to begin with - I still have no idea.